# Where do I get build icon in Eclipse? I want to execute maven job in jenkins from Eclipse IDE

Tags: jenkins, eclipse-plugin

[image]

I need to find the above icon in my Eclipse IDE. I am using Eclipse neon 3.

Comment: Looks like a view from the [Mylyn Husdon/Jenkins Connector](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector#group-screenshots). 
Install it in case you do not have it (via Marketplace). If you got it installed you can open the "builds" view via Menu (Window --> show view --> type in 'builds').

Comment: hey tnx a lot .i got the option.i navigated to the jenkins connector link provided by you and downloaded

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you dont have a build icon. You should right click on the project and then click Export.. and you can choose the type of Export (.war file, .jar file, it depends)

Comment: Lucas tnx for the answer but i m looking for build icon in eclipse